# UWP App FileLoadException WindowsRuntime only occurs on mobile

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I've been having trouble with my app after deploying the store generated bundles onto my Windows 10 Mobile device. I also uploaded this to the app store review team but they are constantly seeing a crash. So I created a blank project to try and find out what the issue was.

The blank app just contains a function to try and find a folder using the StorageFolder API. If it doesn't exists then it just displays a message saying it wasn't found. I also surround this function with a try/catch because I believe this area of the code is the culprit of my problems.

Here is the blank project on Github: https://github.com/cmakthat/MobileCrashTesting

Here are the generated bundles from Visual Studio: https://1drv.ms/f/s!Anec4-FVkNsbhdtfR82xskiDviPW6g

More specifically, here is the code too:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace MobileTestingCrash
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
        /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

            try
            {

                deleteTempClips();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageDialog dia = new MessageDialog("App init exception: " + ex.ToString());
                dia.ShowAsync();
            }
        }

        public static async void deleteTempClips()
        {
            StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

            IStorageItem storageItem = await storageFolder.TryGetItemAsync("Temp");

            if ( storageItem == null )
            {
                MessageDialog dia = new MessageDialog("Item never found");
                dia.ShowAsync();
            }
            return;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
        /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a specific file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                }

                // Place the frame in the current Window
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
            {
                if (rootFrame.Content == null)
                {
                    // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                    // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                    // parameter
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
                }
                // Ensure the current window is active
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when Navigation to a certain page fails
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The Frame which failed navigation</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation failure</param>
        void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
        /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
        /// of memory still intact.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
        private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the rundown when deploying to my Windows 10 Mobile device:

- Deploy in debug mode on Visual Studio: Works
- Deploy in release mode on Visual Studio: Works
- Deploy the "_Test" bundle: Works
- Deploy the "appxupload" bundle within it: FileLoadException

The FileLoadException I am getting is shown in this image:
[image: FileLoadException image]

So now I'm at a lost on what to do. I can't get my app approved by the store because of this blocker. My original project was working a few weeks ago, but now suddenly I'm starting to get these crashes and I haven't changed anything major. Any ideas?

Comment: If the answer is helpful please consider [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it

Answer (score 0):

> Deploy the "appxupload" bundle within it: FileLoadException

You can't deploy the `appxupload` into mobile directly. Because the `appxupload` file is not complete. You could verify this via modify the `appxupload` file suffix name to `zip` and explore it. It contain two files, `appxbundle` file and `appxsym` file.

[image]

And the `appxsym` will be used when `appxupload` file upload to store. It will make complete `appxbundle` file after store cloud compilation. And the complete file is equal to  **_Test** bundle that described in your case.

[image]

So, It is not a good practice that *Deploy the "appxupload" bundle*.